# how to generate sequence id without procedure?

Tags: sql-server-2005

```
SELECT
  ID
  ,sender
FROM 
SELECT 'squence ID' AS ID, 'blabla' AS sender
FROM A
```

The question: is it possible to somehow generate 'sequence ID' without any procedure?

Comment: Without knowing the db your using it's impossible to answer this question.

Comment: @ntziolis - strange comment seeing as he tagged it sql-server-2005.

Comment: Your question is not clear - what kind of sequence generator are you thinking about? How is it supposed to come from `A`?

Comment: @Oded you are right, sry for that, it's just to early I guess ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use row_number(), like this:

```
SELECT row_number() over (order by sender) as Id, 'blabla' AS sender
FROM A
```